# Apache httpd basic auth bypass popup with html/jsp page

Tags: apache, authentication, popup

I want to replace Apache's httpd basic authentication(**pop up based**) with a normal **form-based** login page.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!!! Hope it may help some one.

Apache httpd server internally supports **mod_auth_form,** using that we can get credentials from user by showing form-based login page.

*how to use mod_auth_form* - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html

Way to preserve the request uri:

**Connect via AJP protocol.**

*Basic flow* -  Httpd asks for user credentials & authenticates the user. If valid user found, then it will share remote user details with Tomcat via AJP port. This will preserve the incoming URI request to httpd.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to preserve the URI?

Comment: Yeah, my previous comment speaks about that. We can use mod_auth_form to authenticate the user and then pass him to the requested URL.