# httpd/mod_auth_form preserve & redirect with incoming uri after authentication

Tags: apache, redirect, uri, preserve, mod-auth-form

I am blocked with this issue:

> Dealing with: Apache httpd, Tomcat, mod_auth_form and mod_jk.

---

> issue:

currently using mod_auth_form to load login page in apache httpd for authentication. so on redirecting to login page, the incoming uri is lost. After successful authentication I have to redirect to a webapp hosted in tomcat with the previous uri, bcoz the webapp needs to process the info.

---

So is there any way to save the incoming request in apache httpd and after authentication just do a redirect to tomcat with mod_jk ??.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hi @n3rve, did you find any solution?. This post - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356046/apache-httpd-basic-auth-bypass-popup-with-html-jsp-page) has an updated answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by a trick with Apache httpd using an **Inline Login flow.**

Basically when a user tries to access a protected resource, then httpd will show him the login form (configured as error document) within the same page without redirecting the user to login page.

**Basic inline example**

```
AuthFormProvider file
ErrorDocument 401 "/login.shtml"
AuthUserFile "conf/passwd"
AuthType form
AuthName realm
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://example.com/login.html"
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/
```

**Example inline login form**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
  Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

refer - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html (Inline Login)

This will help to preserve the incoming URI and when user clicks the login button, if the authentication is successful then the user will be granted to access the resource.

So this will avoid page redirect to login page and in turn this preserves the page state & contents.